# How to install puppet devel from apt.puppetlabs.com?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, puppet

According to the [README](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/README.txt) at [apt.puppetlabs.com](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/) the repo is added by

```
wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
```

but I only see the stable 2.7 version when I afterwards search in `aptitude`.

Even if I install [release-unstable](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-unstable.deb), I still only see the 2.7 version.

The devel version is listed in the [Packages](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/unstable/devel/binary-amd64/Packages) file.

```
Package: puppet
Version: 3.0.0-0.1rc3puppetlabs1
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Puppet Labs <info@puppetlabs.com>
Installed-Size: 492
Depends: puppet-common (= 3.0.0-0.1rc3puppetlabs1), ruby1.8
Recommends: rdoc
Suggests: puppet-el, vim-puppet
Section: admin
Priority: optional
```

So I suppose it is possible?

**Question**

How to install puppet 3.0 rc3 on Ubuntu 12.04 from apt.puppetlabs.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like they have a `/devel` branch in their sources, as opposed to the `/main` that systems will typically use.

I presume their "setup" package creates a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?  You'll want to modify the source line(s) in that file - where it says `main` at the end of the line, you'll want to replace that with `devel`.  Run an `apt-get update` and the 3.0rc3 packages should be recognized as current.

Just to clarify on `unstable`: what that refers to is the [unstable release of Debian](http://www.debian.org/releases/sid/), not necessarily unstable puppet packages.  What you're probably getting there is stable packages for an unstable OS.